# Open Iframe with clickable image on same page?

Tags: php, wordpress, flash, iframe

im creating new website and i want to know how i insert one clickable image to open one iframe on my blog post...

I want to add for example 3 clickables images and each image have different iframe for appear when click on that

How i do that?

Comment: my iframe already working, here is the code what i use actually [iframe src="http://xxxxx.com/xxxx.php" width="100%" height="500"] this is what one plugin on wordpress suggested me to add.. but i want to add one image for example "Click here to watch" and open the iframe, understand?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting it as a comment

Comment: i have edited my question.